Extensions of non-degenerate representations of C*-Algebras
I'm aware of the result that if $A$ is a $C^{*}$-algebra and $\pi: A \longrightarrow \mathcal{B}(H)$ is a non-degenerate representation, then $\pi$ uniquely extends to a representation $\overline{\pi}: M(A) \longrightarrow \mathcal{B}(H)$.
However in many papers I've read, we study non-degenerate representations $\pi: A \longrightarrow M(B)$, for $B$ some $C^{*}$-algebra, possibly non-elementary (so not isomorphic to $\mathcal{K}(H)$ for some $H$), and I've seen it stated several times that there exists a canonical extension $\overline{\pi}: M(A) \longrightarrow M(B)$.
However, I don't see a way of porting the result from the result I do know.  I initially thought perhaps we could use the universal representation $\varphi: A \longrightarrow \mathcal{B}(H)$ and somehow get a commutative diagram:

and get something like this.  However I'm not sure if this is actually how this result is proven ,or if it uses an entirely different technique.  I would highly appreciate a reference to this result, or a proof of how this more general statements is shown.

I realized there is a need for clarification: what exactly does “non-degenerate” means in this context? Because usually $\pi: A \to B$ being non-degenerate means $\pi(A)B$ is dense in $B$, but that is not the notion of non-degeneracy when considering a representation $\pi: A \to B(H)$, which is $\pi(A)H$ being dense in $H$. While $K(H) \subset B(H)$ is non-degenerate in the second sense, it is not non-degenerate in the first sense.

I'm not sure what you mean.  A representation $\pi: A \longrightarrow \mathcal{B}(H) = M(\mathcal{K}(H))$ satisfies $\overline{\pi(A)H} = H$ if and only if $\overline{\pi(A)\mathcal{K}(H)} = \mathcal{K}(H)$ (so that the two senses of nondegeneracy are the same).

I suppose the question is whether by $\pi: A \to M(B)$ being non-degenerate, you meant $\pi(A)B$ is dense in $B$ or $\pi(A)M(B)$ is dense in $M(B)$. I guess you meant the former then?
